# Microsoft Authentication Library (msal) with Power Automate (prev called Microsoft Flow)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, power-automate

I would like to generate new tokens (from Microsoft graph api) and reuse tokens (until they expire) using power automate. However I do not see any built in connectors to use msal. One solution is as below:
[image]

However as you can see, each time the table is modified, it generates a new token. I would like to avoid this step and instead use token cache until I am required to generate new token.
I see that 3rd party libraries (python, c# etc) provide this capability. Given such libraries exist, how can I leverage them to securely generate and reuse tokens - do I have to create a custom connector and invoke a python script (utilizing msal lib) from Azure functions? If so, this looks a bit convoluted since MSAL is integral and part and parcel of MS, so I was hoping for more direct integration with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Each action in Power Automate / PowerApps (with the exception of stuff like the HTTP action, which is not really designed to handle any sort of complex authentication standard) implicitly includes an authentication setup that is handled behind the scenes so that you don't have to worry about it, including prompting the user to grant permissions, login with their MS account etc.

If you need to use an authentication setup that isn't covered, or pair your own HTTP call with an authentication standard the first port of call is definitely custom connectors - they provide a variety of ways to authenticate a connection, and handle delegated permissions, tokens, user approvals, etc all in the background, including a variety of MS standards.

Comment: Yeah ... thats what I ended up doing - creating a custom Azure function API that handles authentication and reuse of tokens from cache and using the http connection from flow to connect to this custom az fn api.